# Trouble with Yarn and Duplicate Modules from Jest

Tags: react-native

Alright let's see if i can even explain this well enough - I'm really hoping someone can provide some assistance because this is driving me crazy.

We use yarn to pull packages for our RN projects.

Let's say I have two versions of our project (more or less accurate, but easier to explain) version 0.5 and version 0.6.

When I run yarn on version 0.5 the node-modules directory is populated as expected - different packages show up etc etc, but the content looks like this:

> node-modules
>
> > react-native-package
> >
> > > node-modules
> > >
> > > > .bin

When I run yarn against version 0.6, the node-modules directory contains the same folders, however, if those packages have a package.json file, yarn is also pulling that content down as well.

> node-modules
>
> > react-native-package
> >
> > > node-modules
> > >
> > > > .bin
> > > >         some-folder-1
> > > >         some-folder-2
> > > >         some-folder-3

Naturally, this means that jest freaks out because it's finding all sorts of duplicate modules, like react-animate, or react-native.

There is nothing significantly different that i can see between version 0.6 and 0.5, other than the js files that make up the project. Even the package.json file is nearly identical (just the project version number is different.)

If anyone has any insight into this one it would be incredibly helpful. I'm sure I've just missed something at this point, but it's incredibly frustrating.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, this was a result of an incomplete migration from RN 0.57 to 0.59.  After using [RNDiff](http://react-native-community/rn-diff-purge:%20Easier%20React%20Native%20...%20-%20GitHub%20https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge) to manually complete the migration instead of trying to rely on the built in upgrader this issue resolved itself.